# How to point elasticsearch alias to current index and removing the alias from old index from index template?

Tags: elasticsearch

In our application , we are creating the elasticsearch index daily basis and index pattern is index-. (eg. index-17-09-2019). But our application is accessing the index through an alias which is pointing the current index. Now attaching and removing of the alias with the index is done through a cron job. Is it possible to do it through through index template as we are avoiding the cron job.
We can attach alias with the index through index template but I am not sure whether we can detach the alias with the old index and add it to the new index through index template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with built-in index lifecycle management (ILM). Your application will be sending data to index alias and ILM will take care of the rest.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/using-policies-rollover.html) is the description of how it can be done, but basically you need to:

**1. Create ILM job**

```
PUT /_ilm/policy/my_policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "1d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Create an index template with ILM policy attached**

```
PUT _template/my_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["test-*"], 
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy", 
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "test-alias" 
  }
}
```

**3. Start the process by creating init index**

```
PUT test-000001 
{
  "aliases": {
    "test-alias":{
      "is_write_index": true 
    }
  }
}
```

That will help you with handling creation of new index every day without external CRON job. You can also extend your policy, later on to e.g. [delete old indices after 7 days after rollover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html#set-up-lifecycle-policy).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. Got your point. But my application is only reading the data from elasticsearch and elasticsearch is being loaded through logstash that basically scheduled once in a day and it loads fresh data from db to a new index every day. My application should read the data only from new index every day. So we created alias. So how to handle this situation?

Comment: Rollover action will take care of creating write alias to a newly created index, you can find it with the query `GET /alias_name/_alias`.