# Problem with rotating (ILM) Cloudflare indices on ELK cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, cloudflare, elk, ilm

The problem I have is that my Cloudflare indices report the following ILM errors:

- on index with alias: `illegal_argument_exception: rollover target [cloudflare] does not point to a write index`
- on index without alias: `illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [cloudflare] does not point to index [cloudflare-2022.08.13-000001]`

Basically what I was able to find out is that when a new index is created, it doesn't receive the alias from `rollover_alias`:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "lifecycle": {
        "name": "cloudflare",
        "rollover_alias": "cloudflare"
      },
```

option which makes the rollover fail. When I assign the alias manually to all indices affected, rollover and ILM starts to work again but I want to understand why does it happen and find out a permanent solution to this problem. Otherwise I will have to check this cluster manually and force moving the data from HOT to WARM nodes when the HOT storage fills up.

The setup on Cloudflare is based on [this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/data-products/analytics-integrations/elastic) guide, in other words Cloudflare pushes the logs to S3 bucket, then AWS Lambda pushes them to ELK (elastic.co).

Cloudflare index template in question:

```
  "cloudflare": {
    "index_patterns": [
      "cloudflare-*"
    ],
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "observer.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "cloudflare.parent.ray_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.worker.subrequest_count": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.origin.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.rate.limit.id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "user_agent.version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.device.type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.pathing.op": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.os.version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "source.port": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.server.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "cloudflare.security_level": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "observer.vendor": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "event.dataset": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.worker.cpu_time": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "http.response.status_code": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "user_agent.minor": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.cache.response.status": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "user_agent.patch": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.colo.id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "user_agent.os.full": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "source.address": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.build": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "source.as.number": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.start.timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "cloudflare.waf.rule.id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.origin.ssl.protocol": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http.request.bytes": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "source.geo.country_iso_code": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.pathing.src": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.response.bytes": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.response.status": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.waf.rule.message": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.origin.response.time": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "url.path": {
          "fields": {
            "path": {
              "index": true,
              "eager_global_ordinals": false,
              "fielddata": false,
              "index_options": "positions",
              "index_phrases": false,
              "norms": true,
              "type": "text",
              "store": false
            }
          },
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.response.compression_ratio": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "cloudflare.worker.subrequest": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "cloudflare.cache.response.bytes": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.waf.profile": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.waf.flags": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.firewall.matches.actions": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.http.response.status_code": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "user_agent.os.platform": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.waf.matched_var": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.os_minor": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.worker.status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.firewall.matches.rule_ids": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.os_major": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.origin.response.bytes": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "source.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "http.response.bytes": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "cloudflare.client.ssl.protocol": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "url.full": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "client.address": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.os_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.end.timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "cloudflare.origin.response.http.last_modified": {
          "ignore_malformed": true,
          "type": "date"
        },
        "user_agent.original": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.cache.tiered.fill": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "cloudflare.origin.response.http.expires": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "E, d MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"
        },
        "user_agent.name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.waf.action": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.cache.status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.request.host": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "source.geo": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "region_code": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "longitude": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "region_iso_code": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "region_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "country_code2": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "ip": {
              "type": "ip"
            },
            "continent_code": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "postal_code": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "country_code3": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "latitude": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "city_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "dma_code": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "country_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "continent_name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "timezone": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.rate.limit.action": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.client.ssl.cipher": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.os.name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.pathing.status": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.zone_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "client.port": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "observer.type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http.request.referrer": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.major": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "event.end": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "cloudflare.client.request.protocol": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "user_agent.device.name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "destination.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "url.domain": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http.request.method": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.firewall.matches.sources": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.response.content_type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.ray_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "event.start": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "ecs.version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "client.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "cloudflare.edge.colo.code": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "http.version": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "cloudflare.client.ip.class": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "server.ip": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "user_agent.os.kernel": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": {},
    "order": 0,
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "mapping": {
          "ignore_malformed": "true"
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "lifecycle": {
          "rollover_alias": "cloudflare",
          "name": "cloudflare"
        },
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": null
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ILM Policy in quesion:

```
{
  "cloudflare": {
    "policy": {
      "phases": {
        "cold": {
          "actions": {
            "set_priority": {
              "priority": 0
            }
          },
          "min_age": "30d"
        },
        "warm": {
          "actions": {
            "set_priority": {
              "priority": 50
            }
          },
          "min_age": "0ms"
        },
        "hot": {
          "actions": {
            "rollover": {
              "max_age": "1d"
            },
            "set_priority": {
              "priority": 100
            }
          },
          "min_age": "0ms"
        },
        "delete": {
          "actions": {
            "delete": {
              "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
            }
          },
          "min_age": "60d"
        }
      }
    },
    "modified_date": "2021-11-02T17:18:34.417Z",
    "in_use_by": {
      "indices": [
        "cloudflare-2022.07.09-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.08-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.04-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.06-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.07-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.05-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.10-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.12-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.11-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.13-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.03-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.01-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.04-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.08-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.18-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.06-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.07-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.16-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.14-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.09-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.05-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.03-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.23-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.21-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.02-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.11-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.13-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.01-000017",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.17-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.18-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.28-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.27-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.24-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.01-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.22-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000023",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.03-000024",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000021",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.23-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000022",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.12-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.06-000027",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.13-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.07-000028",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.19-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.16-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.26-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.09-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.05-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000020",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.15-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.20-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.08-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.10-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.04-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.03-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.31-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.14-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.25-000004",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.21-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.25-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000018",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.02-000019",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.29-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.26-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.27-000009",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.30-000015",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.30-000014",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.31-000016",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.30-000013",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.27-000010",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.30-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.28-000011",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.17-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.29-000012",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.27-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.29-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.25-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.30-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.26-000008",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.22-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.26-000007",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.31-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.26-000006",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.24-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.26-000005",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.20-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.24-000003",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.28-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.29-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.16-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.19-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.15-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.09-000030",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.25-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.26-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.02-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.21-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.20-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.24-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.05-000026",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.04-000025",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.14-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.10-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.15-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.11-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.08-000029",
        "cloudflare-2022.08.07-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.28-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.17-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.06.06-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.05.22-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.01-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.12-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.30-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.27-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.23-000001",
        "cloudflare-2022.07.23-000002"
      ],
      "data_streams": [],
      "composable_templates": []
    },
    "version": 12
  }
}
```

Elastic version: `v7.16.2` provided by elastic.co on AWS

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/aliases/cloudflare?v&s=i:asc`

Comment: @Val This is what I'm getting: https://pastebin.com/M58pfMAf

Comment: Ok, I think [task 3](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/data-products/analytics-integrations/elastic#task-3---configure-the-deployment) is missing an important step, which is to [create the initial index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-up-lifecycle-policy.html#create-initial-index) at the very beginning.

Comment: Can it even be created at this point?

Comment: Yes, you can [add the alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/aliases.html#write-index) to the current write-index

Comment: That's what I did before but the problem will reappear in a few days and that's what bothers me the most.

Comment: You didn't mention assigning any write index alias and the output you shared also doesn't contain an index being the current write index. You just mentioned that " you assigned the alias manually"

Comment: Okay, let's give it a shot. But won't it stop working when the new index will be created?

Comment: Okay, after doing so, eight indices without alias report lifecycle errors, so I have to assign an alias to them manually.

Comment: Will u be able to test if this solution works for you? Because you cannot always manually assign alias to an index. First you will need to create an ILM policy , then create an index template and assign to ILM policy once this is done create an index and ensure that write is set to true. Once the ILM policy is met it will automatically create new indices in this example it would be test-000001 
 then test-000002 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974267/how-to-point-elasticsearch-alias-to-current-index-and-removing-the-alias-from-ol

Comment: 1/2 Hey, thanks for your reply. I have ILM policy and index template linked with the policy already there but when the new index is created, it doesn't inherit the alias which breaks the ILM and results in the errors I posted above. When I assign the alias manually to the newest index with `is_write_index` set to true, it starts working until the next day. I am not sure how creating a new index can help but I can definitely try. Now I have `cloudflare-2022.08.21-000001` and `cloudflare-2022.08.20-000001`, bot of these indices are linked to the `cloudflare` template and ILM policy.

Comment: 2/2 But they don't inherit the alias, then I have `cloudflare-2022.08.22-000001` that's 7GiB of size and `cloudflare-2022.08.22-000001` that's 452b of size, the former doesn't have the alias but the latter does have it.

ILM doesn't happen until manual intervention of assigning the aliases to the indices and forcing ILM on them.